# Is exact cover with sumsets NP-Complete

Tags: np-complete

Given a group $G$, the sumset of two sets $A,B$ is denoted as $A+B = \{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$. We have that $A+B$ has no multiplicities if $|A+B| = |A||B|$. For practically, let's say $G$ is integer addition modulo $N$.

We define an exact cover-eqsque problem. We let $[N] = \{0,1\dots N-1\}$.

**Input:** a set, $S$ of subsets of $[N]$

**Output:** a map $\phi: S \to 2^{[N]}$, such that $\bigcup_{A \in S}A+\phi(A) = [N]$, and $\sum_{A\in S} |A||\phi(A)| = N$

Can we show that this problem is NP-complete in terms of the parameter $N$?

Comment: Given $A$, is there a nice characterization of the $B$ for which $|A+B|=|A| |B|$?